# PostgreSQL Join table as JSON object array from JSON-encoded array of IDs

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I am looking for syntax to load another table's rows according to a JSON-encoded list of IDs, and return the resulting query as a JSON array of objects.

My use case is storing simple lists of references as ID arrays in a JSON field rather than in a separate table of entries.

The first use case is returning the expanded (translated from IDs to objects) JSON array from an INSERT (because I hope to get this behaviour returning from INSERT as well). This is the closest I think I got: Nothing I've tried has run successfully.

```sql
CREATE TABLE image_upload (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    image_filename VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    image_width INTEGER NOT NULL,
    image_height INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE image_strip (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    image_ids JSON NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO image_upload (created_at, image_filename, image_width, image_height)
    VALUES (NOW(), 'test.png', 100, 100);
INSERT INTO image_upload (created_at, image_filename, image_width, image_height)
    VALUES (NOW(), 'test2.png', 100, 100);

INSERT INTO image_strip (created_at, updated_at, image_ids)
    VALUES (NOW(), NOW(), '[1,2]')
RETURNING id, created_at, updated_at,
    (SELECT json_agg(iu)
        FROM image_upload iu
        INNER JOIN ROWS FROM(json_array_elements(image_ids)) WITH ORDINALITY AS x(id, ord)
        ON x.id = iu.id
        ORDER BY x.ord) AS images;
```

Comment: Don't do this, use a proper relation table with foreign keys.

Comment: If you insist (and I admit storing an array makes it easier to order the collection), at least use an array of integers (`int[]`), not a json something - which might not be an array, or not contain numbers. And this is in fact your issue - your join tries to compare a `json` value against an `int`eger.

Comment: [Casting `x.id::text::int`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=201f642575f079110316df5f5b59ae92) would work, but I really recommend [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=674c9b0fedaa50c09533f7b0da7aff09).

Comment: Thanks for the int[] tip and demo @Bergi, if you want to post that as answer I'll accept it